# How to access image dimensions embedded in an SVG?

Tags: javascript, svg

I have several SVGs, where some have images embedded within them. I want to read the height and width properties of these images, and compare that to the height and width of the SVG itself so that I can determine the ratio between the sizes.

How can I access the properties of the embedded image? I am using javascript and typescript.

Comment: SVGImage element doesn't expose this information, you would have to go through an HTMLImage element to grab it.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Lurg9m3a/

Comment: @ChrisG this only returns the `width` attribute of the element, nothing about the loaded media, and thus, nothing useful to set its aspect ratio.

Comment: @Kaiido I get that, but the question asks about how to read the properties. Maybe they do have those in the svg source?

Comment: @ChrisG I honestly doubt of your reading, but I may be wrong, so let's OP ping me (`@Kaiido`)  in case you are right so I can reopen.